# how to save my captured image in gallery folder or phone memory?

Tags: netbeans, java-me

I am using nokia 3120 and I want to save captured image in phone memory but when I save my image it give Exception Security `Java/lang/SecurityException`  Access denied.

my code,

```
FileConnection fileConn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;

        try {
            fileConn = (FileConnection) Connector.open(
                    "file:///C:/story123.jpg");    /*//"file:///root1/story123.jpeg");*/
            if (!fileConn.exists()) {
                fileConn.create();
            }
            dos = new DataOutputStream(fileConn.openOutputStream());
            dos.write(photo);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();
            fileConn.close();

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("Error!" + ioe);
        }
```

Comment: That phone doesn't support Java/J2ME, read the [Specification](http://www.gsmarena.com/nokia_3210-6.php) here.

Answer (score 3):

J2ME is very strict. Probably the phone does not allow to store something in the root folder of the file system.
Try to find the images folder, and store it there.

You may get the directory with

System.getProperty("fileconn.dir.photos")

See also
[FileConnection API system properties in the Symbian platform and Series 40](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!implementation-notes/jsr-75-fileconnection-api-optional-package/runtime-environment-notes/system-properties.html)